# How do I invoke a function whenever a property of an object is read?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

We can use this pattern to create hooks when reading a property from an object:

```
const obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'x', {
    get: function () {
      return require('x');
    }
});
```

I am wondering if there is a way to create a hook when reading *any and all* properties on an object such as obj?

For example, when code tries to access property 'y' which doesn't exist on `obj` yet, the hook will still get invoked.

*That's the key part*: if I knew all of the object's properties ahead-of-time, I could loop through them. But in this case, properties may be added to the object later, or an unanticipated property may get read (end-user will call something unexpected.)

Comment: Have a look at [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which is a new ECMAScript 2015 feature and allows you to define custom behavior for certain internal methods such as getting properties. Implementing the [`handler.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) trap allows for a certain function to be called whenever a property is accessed:

```js
const obj = {};
const proxyObj = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    console.log('accessed');
  }
});
proxyObj.foobar; //A property is accessed and the console is logged to
```

Here, accessing any property of `proxyObj` will result in a log in the console. All "trap" means here is that the getting of the property value is *intercepted*, or trapped, and then you can invoke custom behavior when it happens. `target` here is the target object (`obj`), `property` is the property being accessed and `receiver` is the proxy. To apply it here, check if `property` is `y`:

```
if(property === 'y') {
  ...
}
```

It doesn't matter if the property exists or not, the trap is still invoked. There's a variety of other traps you can set such as setting a property, using the `in` operator, using the `delete` operator, etc. You can see them all at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Methods_of_the_handler_object).

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Li beat me to it, but here is a real example, which is my use case:

// async and bluebird libraries are both installed in my local project

```
let obj = {};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return require(property);
  }
});

const {async, bluebird } = proxy;
console.log('bluebird => ', bluebird);
```

now I can inject this proxy object anywhere, and myself or the end user can easily access dependencies. The purpose is so that you don't need to pre-load dependencies if you don't actually need them. It also saves a few lines of code here and there.